# Looping through table function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an application that is based on Symfony framework with the pages built out in HTML, I have multiple tables that will have varying row length with inputs on each row and I need to loop through all of the data.

My table has this form:

```
<form onsubmit="runScript()">
<div id="{{ tblName }} ">
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>col1Name</th>
   <th>col2Name</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td><input type=text /></td>
   <td><input type=date /></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<button type="submit></button>
</div>
</form>
```

The runScript() function grabs the tables name and spits it into a javascript function I made to rotate through the cells and push them into an array:

```
function getTableData(tblName){
    let div = $(tblName);

    let table = $(div).find("tbody");



    let tableData = [];


    let rowlength = table.rows.length;


    for(let i=0; i<rowlength; i+=1){
        let row = table.rows[i];

        let cellLength = row.cells.length;

        for(let y=0; y<cellLength; y+=1){
            let cell = row.cells[y];

            tableData.push(cell);
        }
    }
    alert(tableData);
}
```

**Update on question: I keep receiving an error of cannot find 'length' of undefined when running through the for loop.

Is there a better way to make this function? there are about 19 tables I need to loop through so I would rather not have to do a separate one for each form.

Thanks!

Thank you @fejanto,
I got it to work, here is the updated javascript:

```
function getTableData(tblName){
    let div = $(tblName);

    // By doing '[0]' on a jQuery object you get the wrapped HTML element
    let table = $(div).find("tbody")[0];

    console.log(table);

    let tableData = [];

    let rowlength = table.rows.length;

    for(let i=0; i<rowlength; i+=1){
        let row = table.rows[i];

        let cellLength = row.cells.length;

        for(let y=0; y<cellLength; y+=1){
            let cell = row.cells[y];

            tableData.push(cell);
        }
    }
    console.log(tableData);
}
```

and the runScript() function:

```
function runScript(){
    let name = $('#tablename').val();

    alert(name);

    getTableData(name);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried logging `tableData` to make sure you've got the right values?  `alert` won't stringify an object, so `[object Object]` may be correct.

Comment: yes, the problem mainly is that after the object:object alert goes away, I receive an error that it cannot find length of undefined.

Comment: You should make a Fiddle so others can help you.  Like this.  https://jsfiddle.net/e1k9252b/

Comment: @BriggsMilburn Maybe something a little more simple might be of some use. [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/6ha0bhc7/) if you want to use the `div` ID as the selector then you can also do that this is example: [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/6ha0bhc7/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.innerHTML` should not be there, you need the HTML collection object, not the html, nor the jQuery object. That's why you need to extract the html collection from the jQuery object.
Also maybe you should use `console.log` instead of `alert` to check the content of your variables, since `alert` won't stringify objects.

```
function getTableData(tblName){
    let div = $(tblName);

    // By doing '[0]' on a jQuery object you get the wrapped HTML element
    let table = $(div).find("tbody")[0];

    console.log(table);

    let tableData = [];

    let rowlength = table.rows.length;

    for(let i=0; i<rowlength; i+=1){
        let row = table.rows[i];

        let cellLength = row.cells.length;

        for(let y=0; y<cellLength; y+=1){
            let cell = row.cells[y];

            tableData.push(cell);
        }
    }
    console.log(tableData);
}
```

Comment: This worked great! It fixed my problem, thank you so much!

Comment: glad to hear that! @BriggsMilburn

Comment: Nice fix on the current source code but maybe something a little more simple might be of some use. [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/6ha0bhc7/)

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, but it seems you are passing the function a string such as "table1", but that isn't the jQuery selector. You're using an ID so the selector should be "#tabel1".

Comment: I updated it on the fiddle to show the connecting function.